# Could not find required file index.html in react js

Tags: reactjs, package.json, docker-container

Hi I am working in react application. I have deployed app in kubernetes. I have below folder structure in react app

[image: Folder Structure]

Below is my Dockerfile

```
# Fetching the latest node image on apline linux
FROM node:alpine AS development

# Declaring env
ENV NODE_ENV development

# Setting up the work directory
WORKDIR /al.web

# Installing dependencies
RUN pwd
RUN ls
COPY ./al.web/package.json /al.web
RUN npm install

# Copying all the files in our project
COPY . .

# Starting our application
CMD npm start
```

When I run the application in kubernetes I get below error

[image: error message when running the container]

I am not sure what configuration is wrong here. Can someone help me to fix the the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want your react app to *start* use **npm start** in the project folder if your project *root* folder isn't installed properly use **npx create-react-app appname**

Comment: Hi Saiprasad, Tried but got same error. do we need to manually copy public folder?

Comment: no if we want to add or delete files we have to do it src folder

Comment: My public folder is outside src folder, when i created project it was outside itself

Comment: what is the exact error you are  facing

Comment: I have updated above screen shot. I have dockerized application and deployed in kubernetes. My container is crashing so i tried see logs and i found error Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /al.web/public

Comment: can we connect through an y desk ill give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250957/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-saiprasad-sp).